# Inserting the date+time into a subject of an email

Tags: php, email, sendmail

How can I insert the date and time at the start of the subject e.g.

the date('d-m-Y h:m:s') in the code doesnt function and returns this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

```
<?php
    mail('joe@example.com', '"date('d-m-Y h:m:s')" Daily Backup: example.com', 'Download your daily backup from this link: http://example.com/backups/backup.zip');
?>
```

This code works: (without the date and time)

```
<?php
    mail('joe@example.com', 'Daily Backup: example.com', 'Download your daily backup from this link: http://example.com/backups/backup.zip');
?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should take the time to read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (section **Variable parsing** is important)

Answer (score 0):

You missed to encapsulate your php-code in the string:

```
mail('joe@example.com', '"'.date('d-m-Y h:m:s').'" Daily Backup: example.com', 'Download your daily backup from this link: http://example.com/backups/backup.zip');
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a syntax error. try to put the date function before you start your string so that it becomes

```
<?php
    mail('joe@example.com', date('d-m-Y h:m:s').' Daily Backup: example.com', 'Download your daily backup from this link: http://example.com/backups/backup.zip');
?>
```